# How Windows determines which certificates have private keys?

Tags: certificate, registry

When I open some certificates in Certificates MMC console, it shows "You have a private key that corresponds to this certificate." string on "general" tab. How does Windows determine which certificates have private keys, and which don't? I think it should be some registry entry, but which?

Answer (score 3):

MMC itself uses the crypto API, and delegates that task to the provider; most likely, it uses [CertificateGetCertificateContextProperty](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa376079%28VS.85%29.aspx) with CERT_KEY_CONTEXT_PROP_ID. The crypto provider then uses an internal strategy. The default crypto provider uses disk-based key storage; in Microsoft\Crypto\RSA\User SID (legacy CSP) or 
Microsoft\Crypto\Keys (CNG); see the [MSDN article on key storage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb204778%28VS.85%29.aspx).